# How to create a WHERE ... OR ... query with MongoDB in Symfony2?

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1, doctrine-odm

Inside my `UserRepository` I want to create custom queries, like the ones I can create with `$dm->createQuery('some query')` when not using MongoDB.

How can I do this? I see that `$this->createQueryBuilder()` method exists, but `$this->createQuery()` does not.

I also tried this as it would make sense, but didn't work:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->where(array('$or' => array(
        array('u.username' => $username),
        array('u.email' => $username)
    )))
    // ...
```

It says that $or is an invalid operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it here: [Doctrine2 Mongodb adding more $or operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452536/doctrine2-mongodb-adding-more-or-operator)

```
/**
 * Adds an "or" expression to the current query.
 *
 * You can create the expression using the expr() method:
 *
 *     $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('User');
 *     $qb
 *         ->addOr($qb->expr()->field('first_name')->equals('Kris'))
 *         ->addOr($qb->expr()->field('first_name')->equals('Chris'));
 *
 * @param array|QueryBuilder $expression
 * @return Builder
 */



/**
 * Adds an "and" expression to the current query.
 *
 * You can create the expression using the expr() method:
 *
 *     $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('User');
 *     $qb
 *         ->addAnd($qb->expr()->field('first_name')->equals('Kris'))
 *         ->addAnd($qb->expr()->field('first_name')->equals('Chris'));
 *
 * @param array|QueryBuilder $expression
 * @return Query
 */
```